# how to enter manual time stamp in get date ()

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to enter manual time stamp in get date () ?

```
select conver(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
```

returns 2010-06-07

now i want to enter my own time stamp in this like 
2010-06-07 10.00.00.000

i m using this in

select * from sample table where time_stamp ='2010-06-07 10.00.00.000'

since i m trying to  automate this query i need the current date but i need different time stamp can it be done .

Answer (score 1):

You just want to append a time to your result? Like this?

```
select convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120) + ' 10.00.00.000'
```

or if you want to get it back to a DATETIME type:

```
select convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120) + ' 10:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--SQL Server 2008
DECLARE @MyTime time, @MyDate date

SELECT @MyDate = GETDATE(), @MyTime = '10:00:00'

SELECT CAST(@MyDate AS datetime) + @MyTime

--SQL Server 2005 and before
DECLARE @MyTime datetime, @MyDate datetime

SELECT
   @MyDate = DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE())),
   @MyTime = '19000101 10:00:00'

SELECT @MyDate + @MyTime
```

"zero" date = 01 Jan 1900 in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(hh, 1, FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)))
```

Once you have the floor of the date, you can add time to it.

[DATEADD(datepart, number, date)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: i need different time stamp but current date

Comment: ya but now if i want to enter 10 o'clock how do i do it it oly alters the date rite? i it to look like this '2010-06-07 10.00.00.000' where 2010-06-07 is the current date

Comment: do i need to add the time in the place of hh